# Error A, R, G, B are not a member of Color

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to fix a vb.net wpf application I did not write. When I do a build I am getting A, R, G, B is not a member of color? Here is the vb code below

```
 With My.Settings
            With .ColorGa67
                cpGa67.SelectedColor = Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
            End With
            With .ColorIn111
                cpIn111.SelectedColor = Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
            End With
            With .ColorPb201
                cpPb201.SelectedColor = Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
            End With
            With .ColorGe68
                cpGe68.SelectedColor = Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
            End With
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With cpGa67.SelectedColor
            My.Settings.ColorGa67 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
        End With
```

I think this has something to do with WPF extender I am not sure when looking at the fromArgb method it isn't much help on what exactly I am doing wrong

the error is on

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With cpGa67.SelectedColor
            My.Settings.ColorGa67 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)
        End With
```

Comment: Why do people use a `With` block to reference *one* element?

Comment: @Plutonix I am not sure why I just got the lovely task of debugging this and fixing it.

Comment: why not My.Settings.ColorGa67 = cpGa67.SelectedColor?

Comment: The whole thing looks like the author is trying to store colors in application Settings, and for that purpose does a conversion of WPF System.Windows.Media.Color to System.Drawing.Color. However, this is not at all necessary. You can directly store System.Windows.Media.Color in Settings.

Comment: Agree with @Clemens and Plutonix. Don't need the With block for  a single element. Can store the color an settings without converting. Probably shouldn't try to reference my.settings as part of it's own with block in a method. But I'm not sure if that last part is just my own preference or a result of the failed approach.

Comment: @Clemens do you have an example of what this should be altered into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually passing .A, .R, .G, and .B as parameters in `Color.FromArgb(.A, .R, .G, .B)?`

Try something like `Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 0, 0)` (using ints as the parameters) to see if that works.

Comment: Also try `Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)` without the fourth parameter (so just the R, G, and B values).

Comment: Hey I did that even though I am not sure what the ints should be but I went to that class and it said they could be from 0 - 255 in the comments so I passed it like you said but I used Color.FromArgb(1,2,3,4) cleared the errors for that part thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you want to pick your colors by RGB, you can find the magic numbers in Paint. Choose Edit Colors on the toolbar (over on the right, next to last) Pick a color and you can see the Red, Green, Blue numbers to the right.

Comment: @josh Glad you found it useful. To Mary's point, if you are looking for a specific color (say, the exact color orange that stackoverflow uses in its logo, you can take a screenshot of the logo, paste into Paint, use the Dropper tool to get that orange, and then look at its details. On a different note, if you are looking to see what colors different RGB combinations make, you can do a general web search for it. An example would be searching "rgb 255 0 100" and seeing that it is a red/pink color.